# Typescript: Have the type of a key or parameter depend on the value of another

Tags: typescript

For a given interface:

```
enum Foo {
    A = 'a',
    B = 'b'
}

Interface Bar {
    name: Foo,
    values: number | number[]
}
```

How can I type `values` in `Bar` to be of type `number` when `name` is `Foo.A`, and `number[]` when `name` is `Foo.B`?

Similarly, for a function:

```
function baz(name: Foo, values: number | number[])
```

How can I type `values` based on the value for `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bar` can be defined as a union where TypeScript can tell what part to expect based on the type of `name` — this kind of union is called a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```typescrpt
type Bar =
    {
        name: Foo.A;
        value: number;
    }
    |
    {
        name: Foo.B;
        value: number[];
    };
```

Similarly, the function can be defined via overloads:

```typescript
function baz(name: Foo.A, values: number): void;
function baz(name: Foo.B, values: number[]): void;
function baz(name: Foo, values: number | number[]): void {
    // Handle checking whether `value` is an array
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAUFdUCCUC8UDkAhvgDRoYBCuBARvigL4ooAuAngA7BQWEBOuculQZRUEIQjAAXLAQA6TAG4hYgG6EANmBnjINYHxWimogD6qRY9BKmz4ceRWPWoG7bvAQDfANoBdF3QGFRQAYzgQAGcWKEJZXgE8JFtdB0USNy0dWQAWACYQ8MiYqBoE-moUyTSFCkz3HKhfAv8ilAAzMBAwlgBLSLLCAC8AClT7BUwG7OAo2S8fAEpZNTg+gBMVLp7+wZoR8ZrJx3qsj3m9b0MAlbd1rc7u3oGQIbGJuTgZi4X9QygZiuPluqweyFUAHpIVAABKEEAbTTcMIAC2AYQA1n0QABzKAAd3RLHRAgABo1gGSoH0onE3vw+IQ2IwgA)

Comment: Discriminated unions (or tagged unions) on TypeScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions